# Why my Rails login fails authentication when running from within an iframe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, authentication, integration

I am trying to integrate my Rails application within another application using the "iframe" technique.

The hosting application has an iframe like that:

```
<iframe src="http://10.0.0.106:3000/" width="800" height="500">
</iframe>
```

This frame retrieves and displays the login page, which is ok. But when I type in username and password to login, it seems that authentication fails and I am prompted again for login. Note that no normal "Wrong username/password" message appears (as it is done when I give wrong username of password). The login form is displayed as if it were the first time I visit it.

Any clue?

Comment: Rails 3? Make sure you have the `csrf_meta_tag` in your iframe content somewhere.

Comment: Yes Rails 3. I have it inside my login layout and inside my main (for other pages) layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the CSRF token is included on the page the only problem that you should experience with iframes is this IE weirdness :

http://www.sympact.net/2008/07/rails-and-ifram.html

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, but the link above is broken. Any help from anyone what it is about?

Answer (score 0):

Is the iframe being served from another domain? This is probably a security feature.

You could turn off the security feature (probably a bad idea), or try other methods of authentication.

Comment: Yes. It is served from another domain. What do you mean I could turn off the security feature. How is it done? And the question is, if I do not switch off the security feature, is it doable to integrate using the iframe technique?

Answer (score 0):

> "Yes. It is served from another domain."
>   — Comment above.

Reason why you are not getting an error message is because the authentication doesn't fail. The cookie that's being stored is for '10.0.0.106:3000' and not your current application. I wouldn't be using an iframe to handle authentication. (Why are you doing this anyway?)

Comment: My customer has a CRM application and they would like to have my application (let us call it "X") appear as a tab in existing CRM web application. One approach they have used in the past of other application was with an iframe and it worked ok (though it didn't require authentication).My "X" application requires authentication.The question is:Is it doable?Can I have an iframe in the CRM application like the one I have in my question above and solve the login problem as well?Or do I have to find another way to authenticate the user who is trying to use my "X" application from within CRM?